# aws - should I integrate s3 upload and store s3 url in dynamodb in one single request?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Table called "Banner".
I have a banner upload function in my UI.

Aws Api gateway is used.
2 resources are created in api gateway,which are /s3 and /banner
I am using 2 separate requests to do this.

**1.POST request, resource: /s3**

This request runs below lambda function, to upload the banner image to s3

UploadBannerToS3.js

```
...
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
...
const data = await s3.upload(params).promise();
...
```

This returns a s3 url storing the banner(as image).

**2. POST request, resource: /banner**

This request take above s3 url as parameter, to store a banner information including the url in dynamodb.

The lambda function will like this.

CreateBanner.js

```
...
const { url} = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const params = {
        TableName : "Banner",
        Item: {
            id: id,
            url: url,
            createdAt: date,
        }
    };
...
const data = await documentClient.put(params).promise();
...
```

In my frontend code(I am using React) will like this.

```
    handleUploadBanner = async (banners) => {

            const image = await toBase64(banner);

            const payload = { "banner": image }
            try {
                // request 1
                const uploadResponse_S3 = await APIHandler.uploadBannerToS3(payload)
                const s3Url = uploadResponse_S3.data.Location;
                // request 2
                const response = await APIHandler.createBanners({
                    url: s3Url,
                })
                console.log(response)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
    }
```

If only request 1 is successfully sent, while request 2 fail to return successful status, would it be a mess for development?

Should I combine these 2 request in one single lambda function to handle it?
What is the best practise to do so?

Comment: Are those different files or the same? You can have as many lambda functions as you wish how did you set the routes (express ? api gateway?). Please improve your question

Comment: Updated above. Thanks

Comment: Curious why you arent just uploading to S3 directly from the client.   What are you gaining by transferring the file to lambda first and using server- side resources tp upload?

Answer (score 2):

1. If end-user (front-end) wants to have a "synchronized" response from API, so it means we need to design 2 apis as synchronized ones. But it doesn't mean we need to merge them.
2. If end-user wants to have only the first api response and doesn't care about the second one, we can design the second apis as asynchronized and you can use the pipeline like

a. Lambda 1  -> Performs its logic -> Send a SNS and return to end-user

b. SNS -> SQS -> Lambda 2

The more we design the system as "single responsibility" is the better for development and maintainance.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

> If only request 1 is successfully sent, while request 2 fail to return
> successful status, would it be a mess for development?

Not necessarily. You could come up with a retry function in front-end for simplicity. But it depends because **mess** it is a very abstract concept. What is the requirement ? It is of vital importance that the requests never fail ? What do you wanna do if they fail ?

> Should I combine these 2 request in one single lambda function to
> handle it?

Either way is better to keep them small and short. It is how you work with aws lambdas.
But I think if you want more control over the outcome with better fail-over approach.

SQS it is one way of doing, however they are complex for that case. I would configure a trigger from s3 to lambda that way you will only update when the images get successfully updated.

So in summary:

1. Call Lambda 1 -> Upload s3 ? Successful ?
2. S3 Triggers Lambda 2
3. Lambda 2 saves to DB

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to process both at one lambda for s3 uploading and db storing. It's simpler and reliable to be said it makes sense to abstracting the fail response.

I mean, the app client is mirroring the file item to dynamodb not the s3. So I will assume, whatever it succeed either failed process we don't need to worries for the app getting wrong link. With some scenarios:

1. succeed upload, succeed db: App client get the correct link
2. succeed upload, failed db: App client will never get the correct link (no item)
3. failed upload, failed db: as same to point #2